# Command line option for one line of program

Tags: command-line

Interpreters for scripting languages and suchlike often provide an option to specify one line of program on the command line itself. For Perl, this option is `-e`; for Python it's `-c`. Which of these is more common? That is, which would be less surprising from a user's viewpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Either one, or none. It mainly depends on the user's previous *background*.

You shouldn't expect either to be *more intuitive* - just put them plain clear in sight, and the users will adjust.

Comment: Yeah, but there must be an answer to which is more common, at least; it would be an unlikely coincidence if they were precisely equally common.

Comment: @rwallace - How do you expect to determine that?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I tried asking here, hoping somebody would have some idea :)

Comment: @rwallace - Sorry, I don't see how anyone could do that.